# Browser not displaying the number 9

Tags: browser, fonts

Using a Chromium browser on macOS 10.14, the number 9 is often not displayed, but is replaced with a hyphen dash.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be caused by bad or duplicate Helvetica fonts—a side effect of the Helvening™, whereby every four years the number of Helveticas on your system doubles (I have 64). Isolated and resolved (in my case) by deleting **HelveticaNeue.dfont, HelveticaNeue-1.dfont** and **HelveticaNeue-2.dfont**.